# Override style of some TBitButtons when using VCL Styles

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl, vcl-styles

I would like to be able to apply a certain style to a handful of BitBtn in an application I am working on.  I have applied a VCL style to skin my whole application.

From what I understood in reading on the web, I could define my own child class of the TBitBtn  and then I could define a style hook for that given class.

I had it work with TLabel and TEdit, but I am not quite sure how to manage it for TButton or TBitBtn. Essentially, I'd like to apply a different background image to the custom TBitBtn rather than the one included in the theme.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want? Either use the code that you already have for the TEdit, or some pseudo-code that would explain what you'd want to do with the TButton.

Answer (score 4):

To modify the appearance of  a `TBitBtn` using the Vcl Styles, depends of your Delphi version

## XE4, XE5

you must create a new style hook derived from the `TBitBtnStyleHook` class and then override the `DrawButton` method. Check this question [`Disabling TButton issue on a VCL styled form`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580563/disabling-tbutton-issue-on-a-vcl-styled-form/9586702#9586702) where I post a sample code that override the `TButtonStyleHook.Paint` method in this case to fix a bug, but you can adapt the same code for your own needs.

## XE2, XE3

The `TBitBtn` doesn't uses style hook on these versions , so your only option is handle the CN_DRAWITEM message for the `TBitBtn`control and then add your own code to draw the button like is explained in this answer [Delphi XE2 VCL styles, How to disable VCL styles on TBitBtn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195687/delphi-xe2-vcl-styles-how-to-disable-vcl-styles-on-tbitbtn)

Comment: It tried TStyleManager.Engine.RegisterStyleHook(TBitBtn, TButtonStyleHookFix); but it does not seem to call my hook on the TBitBtn I have in my form. TStyleManager.Engine.RegisterStyleHook(TButton, TButtonStyleHookFix); works for buttons thoug.  Are TBitBtns using the TButtonStyleHook as well or something else?

Comment: in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195687/delphi-xe2-vcl-styles-how-to-disable-vcl-styles-on-tbitbtn you claim that there is no hook for the TBitBtn

Comment: @Alexandre, sorry but I missed you Delphi Version, in the newest versions of Delphi the `TBitBtn` uses a Style Hook (TBitBtnStyleHook), answer updated.